# Copying files that starts with numbers to another directory

Tags: perl

I've solved #1, But I got 2 question left.
Anyone that can help me?

> 1. From the directory local dir, list all the files that start with a number (0..9) and which file
>      extension is .song
> 2. Create the subdirectory ”local dir/selected” in which you will copy each one of these files after
>      numbering each (non blank) line in each one of them.
> 3. Print out, in a file called stats.txt, the following informations concerning each one of the files:
>      a) Number of (non blank) lines. 
>      b) Number of paragraphs. A paragraph here is a block of text composed of non empty lines and
>      delimited at its beginning and at its end by either the beginning of the file, the end of the file or
>      by a blank line. 
>      c) The mean size of a paragraph (in number of lines).
>      d) If, yes or no, all paragraphs in the file have the same length.
>      Bonus questions:
>      e) Detect each rhymes present in each file.
>      f) Give the ratio of rhyming lines towards the total number of lines.

For #1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory = '/local_dir';

opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR))
{
  # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .song.txt
  next unless ($file =~ m/\.song.txt$/);

  print "$file\n";
}

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Comment: I don't see how your script is currently finding files that start with a number.

Comment: I was wondering if you gave my solution a try. If so, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might go about doing the first and second step:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $src_dir = '';
my @files = glob $src_dir . qq([0-9]*.song.txt);

my $dest_dir = 'selected';
mkdir $dest_dir;

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fin, "<", $file;
    open my $fout, ">", "$dest_dir/$file";
    my $c = 1;
    while (<$fin>) {
        $_ = $c++ . " $_" unless /^$/;
        print $fout $_;
    }
}
```

Rather than using `opendir`, you can use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to find the files that you are interested in, starting with a number `[0-9]` and ending with `.song.txt`. After creating the output directory, the `for` loop goes through these files and creates a new file in the destination directory with the same name. The `while` loop goes through each line of the input file. It adds a number to the start of each line if it is not blank, i.e. the start of the line is not followed immediately by the end of the line `/^$/`. Then it writes the line to the new file.

As for the third step, I think that it would be worth you having a go at that yourself and asking a new question if you get stuck.